# Please comment on this possible answer for abstract duplicate of "integration by partial fractions"

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I've expanded an [old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21112/742) to include a general discussion of how to solve integrals by partial fractions.

Before I add it to the list of abstract duplicates, I'd appreciate corrections and suggestions, and also opinions on whether this is a good abstract duplicate answer or not.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please also modify the question?

Comment: @Aryabhata: I'd like to wait for some feedback on the write-up before I do all that (modify the question to make it more general, add the question to the list of abstract duplicates).

Comment: If you don't modify the question, then people might not be able to judge the answer correctly, IMO. You can always roll back the question to its original. But maybe you are right.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I'm asking for feedback as a general answer; people going there to give me feedback in those terms would know to judge it as an answer to an "abstract duplicate" question, would they not?

Comment: Yeah, it was just a suggestion to avoid people having different versions of the general question in mind. But it is probably not an issue.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Once I get the feedback, if there seems to be a general agreement that it's a good 'abstract duplicate' answer, I'll rewrite the question to include the generalization along the lines of other "abstract duplicate". I'm not objecting to modifying the question eventually, I just want to wait a bit before doing so.

Comment: Yes, I understood that :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've edited the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20963/742) and the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21112/742). I also added it to the [List of generalizations of common question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1868/742), and have flagged it for moderators to turn it into a community wiki.

Comment: Thank you. Please add the faq tag in future.